# android https support in app update

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, https

I have an app live in play store.

1000 + users are active on it already and growing.

But all our web service API's were unsecured, meaning only http.

We encountered someone hacked it easily and started misusing.

Now we want to make our API secured with https endpoints.

But since already users are using our app, if we remove http support,
existing users will fail to make api calls.

We want to update the app with https support.

What would be the best way so that it can be made smooth for existing users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a similar problem by making a redirect from http to https on the server. If this will work in your case it depends on the implementation of your app. Before you trully do this, try it on a test server. Also note that you will need a valid SSL certificate from a known issuer. Android has some built in valid issuers. If you are doing this with a self signed certificate, it will not work as you have to manually tell your application to accept all certificates, but you have not done that in your app with http only.

Comment: Yes, we are using self signed certificate. In our current http only build certificate isn't there. So api calls fill fail even if i redirect http to https. What would be the better solution?

Comment: You could use a proxy, but then again that is not the best solution either. I think it's best to update the app and when the majority of users have moved to new app, drop http. I have also dropped http after a while

Comment: I just found out that you can get a free signed certificate at http://www.startssl.com/ that is your best bet :)